# 'Piping' regex operations

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to clean some strings with a lot of regex operations before passing them to a model.  Previously, I was working on a dataframe level, and I could use pandas' `apply` function to pseudo-pipe my regex operations:

```
# take out website prefixes (e.g. www) and suffixes (e.g. .com, .de, .it)
test['shopname'] = test.shopname.apply(lambda x: x if re.match(r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)',x) is None else re.match(r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)',x).group(3).strip()).apply(lambda x: x if re.match(r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$',x) is None else re.match(r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$',x).group(1).strip())
```

Now, however, I am trying to write a row-level function that could be called with `apply` i.e.

```
test['identified_name'] = test.apply(lambda row: shop_name_cleaning(row['shopname']), axis=1)
```

I don't know how to 'pipe' my strings for subsequent regex operations anymore. My main struggle is to get the code to return the original string if the pattern is not matched, so as to pass it to the next regex operation.

I tried:

```
def shop_name_cleaning(shop_name):
        clean_name = str(re.sub(r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)',x), r'\3', trunc_de043)).str(re.sub(r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$', r'\1', trunc_de043))

return clean_name
```

but Python says:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I also tried:

```
def shop_name_cleaning(shop_name):
        clean_name = str(re.match(r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)', trunc_de043).group(3).strip() or trunc_de043).str(re.match(r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$', trunc_de043).group(1).strip() or trunc_de043)

return clean_name
```

but `or` doesn't work.

I have at least 10 regex operations. I am looking for a solution that doesn't require me to write an insane number of `if`/`else` statements (as I want the original string to be returned if not matched).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
import re

patterns_and_group_numbers = (
    (r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)', 3),
    (r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$', 1)
    )

regexes_and_group_numbers = [(re.compile(pat), group_no) for (pat, group_no) in patterns_and_group_numbers]

def piped_regexes(string):
    for regex, group_no in regexes_and_group_numbers:
        if (m := regex.match(string)):
            string = m.group(group_no).strip()
    return string
```

Comment: That's the elegant code I need!! Thank you!! Just to push it further: if I have two sets of names from two countries, and the regex sets for the two countries are slightly different, is the most efficient way an if statement before the for loop, and have two inputs for piped_regexes i.e. def piped_regexes(string, country), and two sets of regex expressions?

Comment: I can see that working, though it's difficult to comment without seeing the code! In general, though, you should be aware that the "piped regex" approach — though it's readable and fairly elegant — will usually be slower than an extremely long (and, potentially, very ugly!) regular expression that does all your work for you in one go. Python's regular-expression matching runs incredibly quickly because it's written in C, but if you chain lots of operations together, it means the interpreter keeps having to switch between python code and C code, which can lead to inefficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Your actual error is from because you have `str(..).str(...)` and there isn't a `"someting".str(...)` function.

However, you are ignoring the fact that `match` can return `None`. You have to check that `match` actually returned something and if not return the original

```
def shop_name_cleaning(shop_name):
    match = re.match(r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(.*)', shop_name)
    shop_name = match.group(3).strip() if match else shop_name

    match = re.match(r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$', shop_name)
    shop_name = match.group(1).strip() if match else shop_name

    return shop_name
```

If you have too lots of regexes, you can make a helper function and do a reduce - but you must make sure all result groups are addresable the same way e.g. by naming them:

```
from functools import reduce

def clean_name(name, regex):
    match = re.match(regex, name)
    return match.group("out").strip() if match else name
    
    # Or in 3.8+
    return match.group("out").strip() if match:=re.match(regex, name) else name


regexes = [
    r'(.*(?<!-))(www)\.(?P<out>.*)',
    r'(?P<out>.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$',
]

reduce(clean_name, regexes, shop_name)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Faboor. But this is exactly the wordy code chunk I wanted to avoid that's why I tried the other two options, although of course you are right, they don't work. I have >10 regex operations so would need >20 lines of code for your solution. Is there any way I can combine the regex operations?

Comment: @WingyanYip put them in a for loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd tackle the problem:

```
import re

def shop_name_cleaning(shop_name):
    expressions = [r'(?:.*(?<!-))(?:www)\.(.*)',
                   r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$']
    
    for expression in expressions:
        match = re.match(expression, shop_name)
        if match:
            return match.group(1).strip()
        
    return shop_name
```

Just list all possible expressions in `expressions` and make sure that your substring of interest is always in the same capturing (first, second, third, whatever) group and make every other group non-capturing (`(?:...)`). The first match breaks the loop and returns the desired substring.
If all expressions fail, the original `shop_name` is returned.

---

If you actually care which expression has matched (dunno why, but maybe you need it), use a dictionary instead:

```
def shop_name_cleaning(shop_name):
    expressions = {"some_fancy_expression": r'(?:.*(?<!-))(?:www)\.(.*)',
                   "some_other_real_cool_expression": r'(.*)\.(?=\bcom\b|\bde\b|\bit\b|\bco\.uk\b|\beu\b|\blv\b).*$'}

    for key, expression in expressions.items():
        match = re.match(expression, shop_name)
        if match:
            return key, match.group(1).strip()

    return shop_name
```